# Отступ в Navigation Menu

Tags: java, android, xml

Возможно ли добавить divider со своим цветом в 5dp или Bottom margin в 5dp для итемов Navigation меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших стилях можно создать стиль для меню:

```
<style name="NavigationView"  parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/text_lightgray</item>
</style>
```

и в xml самого NavigationView:

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationView"
```

так же вы можете в стилях указать ширину вашей разделительной линии. 
Для регулировки margin можно прописать dimen:

```
<dimen tools:override="true" 
name="design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding">0dp</dimen>
```

Удачи :)

Comment: А для регулировку Margin нужно использовать следующий код https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893072/3740826

Comment: @DuosDuo, спасибо, обновил ответ :)